# In Linux there's "/etc/nginx/sites-available/default", in FreeBSD -?

Tags: freebsd, nginx

In Linux after I've installed nginx, there's a file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` where I can setup my website. However, in FreeBSD such a file isn't created after nginx installation and I can't find it anywhere. Where is it?

Comment: Did you look in /usr/local/etc/nginx? https://www.vultr.com/docs/installing-nginx-on-freebsd

Comment: @ridgy, yes, and that didn't help me. where's the file "sites-available/default"? I see only nginx.conf

Comment: @ridgy there's nothing like **sites-available/default** in `/usr/local/etc/nginx/` at all

Comment: By default, there seems to only be a default main configuration file nginx.conf. You have to modify that and add the necessary files by yourself. See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/nginx-config-file-for-a-website-in-freebsd-and-linux-are-quite-different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FreeBSD have in general a stricter division between the "base system" and third-party software than what Linux has.

FreeBSD will install third-party software under `/usr/local`. This means that you should probably look in `/usr/local/etc` for the configuration files for `nginx`.

Comment: there's nothing like **sites-available/default** in `/usr/local/etc/nginx/` at all

Comment: @user7905648 Related: https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,247364,247371

Answer (score 1):

The `/etc/nginx/sites-available` directory isn't part of the standard nginx package. Ubuntu and other Linux distros have included them, but FreeBSD does not. On the FreeBSD forums, there is a discussion about it [here](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/57611/), and a good tutorial on nginx with FreeBSD with a lot of Q&A [here](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/42312/). It looks like a lot of reading, but the good news is that nginx is very well supported on FreeBSD, and was even developed exclusively on FreeBSD for 10 years.